# After CallKit integration video call app ends the call if power button is pressed

Tags: ios, swift, callkit

After integrating callkit into video call app pressing the power button is ending the call when the call is in progress

Below is the provider configuration:

```
static var providerConfiguration: CXProviderConfiguration {
    let providerConfiguration = CXProviderConfiguration(localizedName: "AppName")
    providerConfiguration.supportsVideo = true
    providerConfiguration.maximumCallsPerCallGroup = 1
    providerConfiguration.supportedHandleTypes = [.phoneNumber]
    return providerConfiguration
}
```

below is CXCallUpdate to report that there is an incoming call:

```
let update = CXCallUpdate()
update.remoteHandle = CXHandle(type: .generic, value: handle)
update.supportsDTMF = true;
update.hasVideo = hasVideo;
update.supportsGrouping = false;
update.supportsUngrouping = false;
update.supportsHolding = false;
```

If we see cisco webex video call, there also callkit has been integrated, but for video call pressing the power button is not ending the call when call is in progress. But pressing the power button is ending the call for audio call. I observed the same behaviour with WhatsApp video call as well.

Comment: In my answer I forgot to mention that the power button doesn't end the call if you're using a headset or if the loudspeaker is on. So, in the case of video calls, the loudspeaker should be on, of course. Maybe you're not turning it on when you're configuring the call.

Comment: Happening same for me. I integrated CallKit with WebRTC. It is working in other places but when the call is in progress pressing the lock button ending the CallKit initiated call.
Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 1):

This is the intended behaviour: if try to do the same thing with the iOS built-in phone app, you'll obtain the same result.

EDIT

The power button ends a call if and only if the call is running through the built-in speaker on top of the screen. In any other case (i.e. the audio is playing through headphones, bluetooth or built-in loudspeaker) the power button will not end the call.

Comment: Also, if we tell to ios call kit that current call is video call it will not end the call on power button press. You can do that by specifying "update.hasVideo = true;"